# passing a variable into url to query DB

Tags: django

in my url I want to pass a key and query the DB on that View, based on that key :

```
#url.py

   path('view/<slug:secret_key>/',DetailMessage.as_view(),name='message'),
```

## view.py

```
class DetailMessage(generic.DetailView):
    model = Message


    template_name = 'msg/view.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        key =self.request.get('secret_key',None) 

        return queryset.get(secret_key=key)
```

But I receive this error :

```
WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url parameters are not stored on the request, but in `self.kwargs`, so you can access this with:

```
class DetailMessage(generic.DetailView):
    model = Message

    template_name = 'msg/view.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            secret_key=self.kwargs['secret_key']
        )
```

Note that a `get_queryset` should return a `QuerySet`, not an *object*. The `get_object` method will, if you do not override it, call `.get()` on the result of `.get_queryset(..)` (after filtering on `pk` or `slug` if it can find these parameters in the URL).